# angular2 component div blur

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

hellow guys, I want to set the element that implement blur.

Therefore,I set the `div` in my code.The `(click)` attribute is be set with the variable `choose`.

**code**

```
public data:any[]=[1,2,3,4];
public choose:number;
public setChoose(index:number){
     this.choose=index;
}
```

**pug**

```
div#mydiv(*ngFor="let item of data;let i = index")
    div((click)="setChoose(i)",[style.choose]="choose==i") {{item}}
```

**css**

```
div{
    background:white;
}
.choose{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Now I accomplish the choose by choose, it seems look like focus.But when I want to set blur effect ,blur is clear the `choose` that the class of choose is removed , I use `@ HostListener("window:click")` and got the `$event` while triggered click event .Unfortunately ,event isn't recognized blur or not by my function.

I hope the host can detect `mydiv` and outside separetely to fulfill focus and blur.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake, you'r using style instead of class

```
div((click)="setChoose(i)",[style.choose]="choose==i") {{item}}


div((click)="setChoose(i)",[class.choose]="choose==i") {{item}}
```

Comment: you misunderstood my meaing,I just confuse focus and blur.
Now the problem was fixed by tabindex which the `div` is be selectable.